# Floating span increases width of div in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, css-float

Hellas,

I'm having a styling issue in IE8. The goal is to have two div's in one row **without setting a width** (div should expand with text). It's working in all browser except for IE. Here the span element I'm floating inside the divs stretches each div to max-width forcing the other div to start in the next row. Here's the jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/TFnsV/

Answer (score 0):

I could not make it work with this html structure in IE7, (In IE8 it works for me).
But you can change the HTML a little like this:

```
<div>
    <h2><span class="left">Test one two three</span>
        <span class="right">USD</span>
    </h2>
    <p>Test test test</p>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.right{
  width: 20px;
```

}

.left{

```
float:left;
```

}

Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zn8cU/

**EDIT:** you can add this:

```
h2{
    text-align:right;
}
```

The updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5bgH2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work. <span class="right">USD</span> is not floating right inside the div. e.g. when I add some text in you jsfiddle the "usd" is attached to the left floated span.

Comment: `<span class="right">USD</span>` is not floating right, but the text is floating left so the "right" span goes right. I tested it in FF, IE7, IE8, and Chrome. What version of IE you check it?

Comment: Your statement is correct and maybe my description was not very clear, but I not only want to have the right span display on the right of the left span, the right span needs to be floated right to have it attached to the right of the div. Compare [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn8cU/1/) to [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TFnsV/11/) The latter is the example I'm trying to achieve in IE...